# type checking works with `if` test inside a function body but not via a function call with the same test

Tags: typescript

Consider the following MWE:

```
function print (x: number) {
  console.log(x)
}

function noString (a: number | string) {
  if (typeof a === 'string') {
    throw new Error('error')
  }
}

export function funOne () {
  const a: number | string = 'abc'

  if (typeof a === 'string') {
    throw new Error('error')
  }

  print(a)
}

export function funTwo () {
  const a: number | string = 'abc'

  noString(a)

  print(a)
}
```

I think `funOne` and `funTwo` are essentially the same. However, I got `[tsserver 2345] [E] Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.` on the last line in `funTwo`.

Why does this happen and how should I avoid this?

Comment: You want: `function noString (a: number | string): asserts a is number {`

Comment: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-type-predicates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because typescript doesn't know that `noString` is used as a type check. But you can tell typescript about it, for example like this:

```
function noString(a: number | string): number {
  if (typeof a === 'string') {
    throw new Error('error');
  }
  return a;
}

export function funTwo() {
  const a: number | string = 'abc';
  print(noString(a));
}
```

Or you could use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
function noString(a: string | number): a is number {
    if (typeof a === 'string') {
        throw new Error('error');
    }
    return true;
}

export function funTwo() {
    const a: number | string = 'abc';
    if (noString(a)) {
        print(a);
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments by @Artyer and @futur, you could also use [asserts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions):

```
function noString(a: string | number): asserts a is number {
    if (typeof a === 'string') {
        throw new Error('error');
    }
}

export function funTwo() {
    const a: number | string = 'abc';
    noString(a)
    print(a);
}
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning `asserts` if they don't want to have to return an unnecessary boolean.

Comment: @futur good point, thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. The first sentence in your answers my question. I came from the Python world, where Pyright will treat all functions like `noString` here as a type check. Hence Pyright can infer that `a` is no longer a string after `noString(a)`.

Comment: @FangHung-chien you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

It's happenning because your `print` function expects a number but is given a string in `funTwo`. When calling `print` function, variable is a string because you've initialized it with 'abc' ***and typescript can't figure out that  `noString` invalidates string types.***

`funOne` is fine because before reaching the `print` function, you have excluded the case of a being a string by throwing an error. The rest of the code is there fore unreachable if variable is of type string. Therefore, passed the `if (typeof a === 'string')` condition, variable `a` can only be a number, so typescript doesn't yell at you.

Solution

If you're sure about the type on funTwo, you can cast it like so:

```
  print(a as unknown as number)
```

Comment: I don't agree with your first paragraph. Indeed, print function in funTwo will not be called with `a` being a string. The case that `a` is string is also excluded in `funTwo` with `noString(a)`, but TS is not aware of this.

Comment: We are aligned on this, @FangHung-chien. TS not being aware leads to a being of its infered type string when called in print of funTwo. going straight to the point made some explanations weak. Edited to emphasize on your point for clarity.